# WinExec throws EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm, shellcode

I tried to modify [this](https://github.com/peterferrie/win-exec-calc-shellcode/blob/master/w64-exec-calc-shellcode.asm) shellcode and make it run notepad.exe instead of calc.exe. I'm `push`ing notepad.exe onto the stack with this code snippet:

```
mov r9, 0x0000000000657865
push r9
mov r9, 0x2e64617065746f6e
push r9
```

Upon `CALL`ing the `WinExec` the `RCX` register points to the `notepad.exe` string.
[image]
But then after entering kernel32.dll `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` exception is thrown.
[image]

This is the full shellcode code:

```
BITS 64
SECTION .text

%define B2W(b1,b2)                      (((b2) << 8) + (b1))
%define W2DW(w1,w2)                     (((w2) << 16) + (w1))
%define DW2QW(dw1,dw2)                  (((dw2) << 32) + (dw1))
%define B2DW(b1,b2,b3,b4)               ((B2W(b3, b4) << 16) + B2W(b1, b2))
%define B2QW(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)   ((B2DW(b5,b6,b7,b8) << 32) + B2DW(b1,b2,b3,b4))
%define W2QW(w1,w2,w3,w4)               ((W2DW(w3,w4) << 32) + W2DW(w1,w2))


; x64 WinExec *requires* 16 byte stack alignment and four QWORDS of stack space, which may be overwritten.
; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx
%ifndef PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT
global shellcode
shellcode:
%ifdef FUNC                               ; assumes stack ends with 8 on entry, use STACK_ALIGN if it might not be.
%ifdef CLEAN                              ; 64-bit calling convention considers RAX, RCX, RDX, R8, R9, R10 and R11
    PUSH    RAX                           ; volatile. Use CLEAN if you want to preserve those as well.
    PUSH    RCX
    PUSH    RDX
%endif
    PUSH    RBX
    PUSH    RSI
    PUSH    RDI
    PUSH    RBP                           ; Stack now ends with 8 (!CLEAN) or is 16 byte (CLEAN) aligned
%endif
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
%ifdef FUNC
    PUSH    RSP
    POP     RAX
%endif
    AND     SP, -16                       ; Align stack to 16 bytes
                                          ; (we can't force it to end with 8 without dummy push and then or)
    PUSH    RAX                           ; Force stack to end with 8 before next push, also saves RSP to restore stack
%elifdef CLEAN
    PUSH    RAX                           ; dummy push to make stack end with 8 before next push
%endif

; Note to SkyLined: instructions on 32-bit registers are automatically sign-extended to 64-bits.
; This means LODSD will set the high DWORD of RAX to 0 if top bit of EAX was 0, or 0xFFFFFFFF if it was 0x80000000.
    PUSH    BYTE 0x60                     ; Stack 
    POP     RDX                           ; RDX = 0x60
%else
%ifdef FUNC
%ifdef CLEAN
    PUSH    RAX                           ; exchanged RDX
    PUSH    RCX
%endif
    PUSH    RBX
    PUSH    RSI
    PUSH    RDI
    PUSH    RBP                           ; Stack now ends with 8 (!CLEAN) or is 16 byte (CLEAN) aligned
%endif
%ifdef CLEAN
%ifndef STACK_ALIGN
    PUSH    RAX                           ; dummy push to make stack end with 8 before next push
%endif
%endif
    MOV     DL, 0x60
%endif
%ifndef USE_COMMON
    ;PUSH    B2DW('c', 'a', 'l', 'c')      ; Stack = "calc\0\0\0\0" (stack alignment changes)
    mov r9, 0x0000000000657865
    push r9
    mov r9, 0x2e64617065746f6e
    push r9
    PUSH    RSP
    POP     RCX                           ; RCX = &("calc")
%endif
    SUB     RSP, RDX                      ; Stack was 16 byte aligned already and there are >4 QWORDS on the stack.
    MOV     RSI, [GS:RDX]                 ; RSI = [TEB + 0x60] = &PEB
    MOV     RSI, [RSI + 0x18]             ; RSI = [PEB + 0x18] = PEB_LDR_DATA
    MOV     RSI, [RSI + 0x10]             ; RSI = [PEB_LDR_DATA + 0x10] = LDR_MODULE InLoadOrder[0] (process)
    LODSQ                                 ; RAX = InLoadOrder[1] (ntdll)
    MOV     RSI, [RAX]                    ; RSI = InLoadOrder[2] (kernel32)
    MOV     RDI, [RSI + 0x30]             ; RDI = [InLoadOrder[2] + 0x30] = kernel32 DllBase
; Found kernel32 base address (RDI)
shellcode_common:
    ADD     EDX, DWORD [RDI + 0x3C]       ; RBX = 0x60 + [kernel32 + 0x3C] = offset(PE header) + 0x60
; PE header (RDI+RDX-0x60) = @0x00 0x04 byte signature
;                            @0x04 0x18 byte COFF header
;                            @0x18      PE32 optional header (= RDI + RDX - 0x60 + 0x18)
    MOV     EBX, DWORD [RDI + RDX - 0x60 + 0x18 + 0x70] ; RBX = [PE32+ optional header + offset(PE32+ export table offset)] = offset(export table)
; Export table (RDI+EBX) = @0x20 Name Pointer RVA
    MOV     ESI, DWORD [RDI + RBX + 0x20] ; RSI = [kernel32 + offset(export table) + 0x20] = offset(names table)
    ADD     RSI, RDI                      ; RSI = kernel32 + offset(names table) = &(names table)
; Found export names table (RSI)
    MOV     EDX, DWORD [RDI + RBX + 0x24] ; EDX = [kernel32 + offset(export table) + 0x24] = offset(ordinals table)
; Found export ordinals table (RDX)
find_winexec_x64:
; speculatively load ordinal (RBP)
    MOVZX   EBP, WORD [RDI + RDX]         ; RBP = [kernel32 + offset(ordinals table) + offset] = function ordinal
    LEA     EDX, [RDX + 2]                ; RDX = offset += 2 (will wrap if > 4Gb, but this should never happen)
    LODSD                                 ; RAX = &(names table[function number]) = offset(function name)
    CMP     DWORD [RDI + RAX], B2DW('W', 'i', 'n', 'E') ; *(DWORD*)(function name) == "WinE" ?
    JNE     find_winexec_x64              ;
    MOV     ESI, DWORD [RDI + RBX + 0x1C] ; RSI = [kernel32 + offset(export table) + 0x1C] = offset(address table)
    ADD     RSI, RDI                      ; RSI = kernel32 + offset(address table) = &(address table)
    MOV     ESI, [RSI + RBP * 4]          ; RSI = &(address table)[WinExec ordinal] = offset(WinExec)
    ADD     RDI, RSI                      ; RDI = kernel32 + offset(WinExec) = WinExec
; Found WinExec (RDI)
    CDQ                                   ; RDX = 0 (assuming EAX < 0x80000000, which should always be true)
    CALL    RDI                           ; WinExec(&("calc"), 0);
%ifdef FUNC
%ifdef CLEAN
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
    ADD     RSP, 0x68                     ; reset stack to where it was after pushing registers
%else
    ADD     RSP, 0x70                     ; reset stack to where it was after pushing registers
%endif
%else
    ADD     RSP, 0x68                     ; reset stack to where it was after pushing registers
%endif
%ifndef PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
    POP     RSP
%endif
%endif
    POP     RBP                           ; POP registers
    POP     RDI
    POP     RSI
    POP     RBX
%ifndef PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT
%ifdef CLEAN
    POP     RDX                           ; POP additional registers
    POP     RCX
    POP     RAX
%endif
    RET                                   ; Return
%else
%ifdef CLEAN
    POP     RCX                           ; POP additional registers
    POP     RDX
%endif
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
    POP     RSP
%endif
%ifdef CLEAN
    POP     RAX
%endif
    RET                                   ; Return
%endif
%endif
```

The only modification is that I'm pushing `notepad.exe` instead of `calc.exe`.
I can't figure out why the exception is thrown and how to fix it.

Shellcode is assembled and linked with:

> ```
> nasm -fwin64 w64-exec-calc-shellcode.asm -o mybuilds\exe\x64-exec-calc-shellcode.obj
> link /MACHINE:x64 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OUT:mybuilds\exe\x64-exec-calc-shellcode.exe /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:shellcode kernel32.lib mybuilds\exe\x64-exec-calc-shellcode.obj
> ```

Comment: Since you push an extra 8 bytes you misalign the stack.

Comment: The stack alignment is the part that I can't really understand. Thank you pointing me in the right direction. I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Even though I really want to figure it out on my own, I can't. I have to ask: how do I fix it?

Comment: push another 8 bytes first.

Comment: I must be dumb, but his didn't help 
```
    mov r9, 0x0000000000000000
    push r9
    mov r9, 0x0000000000657865
    push r9
    mov r9, 0x2e64617065746f6e
    push r9
```

Comment: `add rsp, -8` didn't help either. I'm lost

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but one of the code comments is incorrect: instructions that write 32-bit registers are automatically **zero-extended** to 64-bit, not sign-extended.  [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) quotes Intel's manual.  Also, IDK why you'd put that comment in front of a `push imm8` / `pop r64`.  The 8-bit immediate is sign-extended, but you aren't writing (or even reading) a 32-bit register until `ADD   EDX, DWORD [RDI + 0x3C]`

Comment: Also as Jester said, your "shellcode" contains zero bytes.  NASM will optimize `mov r9, 0x0000000000657865` to `mov r9d, 0x00657865` rather than `mov r9, sign_extended_imm32`, but it's still a 4-byte immediate with a high zero, same as if you'd used it with `push sign_extended_imm32` directly.  (Or with `-O0` you get `mov r9, imm64`.)  Also, you don't need those macros; you're using NASM which has good support for multi-character literals as numeric constants, like `push 'exe'` is exactly equivalent to `push 0x657865`.  (Unlike MASM where it's a total mess or being reversed or not supported.)

Answer (score 0):

> The only modification is that I'm pushing `notepad.exe` instead of `calc.exe`.

Why are you including `.exe` ?

> ```
> ;PUSH    B2DW('c', 'a', 'l', 'c')      ; Stack = "calc\0\0\0\0" (stack alignment changes)
> mov r9, 0x0000000000657865
> push r9
> mov r9, 0x2e64617065746f6e
> push r9
> PUSH    RSP
> POP     RCX                           ; RCX = &("calc")
> ```

I don't see the original version having added `.exe` to `calc`, and if that version works fine then do it like this avoiding embedded zero-bytes (thanks @Jester):

```
mov  rax, B2QW('n', 'o', 't', 'e', 'p', 'a', 'd', '*')
push rax                 ; Stack = "notepad*"
mov  RCX, RSP            ; RCX = &("notepad")
sub  byte [rcx + 7], '*' ; Make zero-terminator: Stack = "notepad\0"
```

Comment: At this moment my main concern is to **understand** the cause of the error I'm getting and I really would appreciate some detailed explanation of why my version doesn't work. 
P.S `PUSH B2QW('n', 'o', 't', 'e', 'p', 'a', 'd', 0` )` doesn't compile.

Comment: @FAMO4S I've corrected my error on the impossible 64-bit immediate `push`. Give it a chance and if it runs fine then start working on the advice that @Jester gave about stack alignment.

Comment: Just ran it. The same exception occurs.

Comment: @FAMO4S Does the original version that has `calc` even run okay?

Comment: It does run okay

Comment: @FAMO4S The solution that I proposed today does not alter the stackpointer differently compared to the original version that you say works. Logically, you can forget about mis-aligned stack then. You'll need to study the topic 'shellcode' in greater detail. (I'm glad I never had to.)

Comment: Note that the original code seems to be avoiding zero bytes. The versions by both of you contain zero bytes. That may cause problems, although the screenshot seems to indicate the code is in memory properly. Anyway, check the location of the actual crash.

Comment: A more convenient way to avoid zeros in the machine code is `mov rax, 'xnotepad'` / `shr rax, 8` / `push rax`.  (And yes, you can use `'xnotepad'` as a 64-bit integer constant in NASM, with the bytes in the immediate matching source order, also matching the order they'll be stored by `mov` or `push`.  The macro is only useful for making sure you remembered to set all the bytes to non-zero values.)  I don't know what Windows wants as an input, though, so IDK what's wrong with the OP's attempts.  Just easier ways to get exactly the same thing.

Comment: From your first screen shot, upon execution of ```call rdi``` instruction, your ```rsp``` is 0x4D932FFA98 which is not 0x10 aligned. In the second screen shot, where highlighted in green, the ```rsp``` value is 0xCA78CFF708 which is again not 0x10 bytes aligned. It is trying to load an ```xmm0``` register into a mis-aligned address by ```movaps``` mnemonic. As such, I guess ```push```ing extra 8 bytes right before ```mov r9, 0x0000000000657865``` makes it to work.